# Need info to Android webview window.open() and window.close()

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android application. It is a WebView for my website. The website contains a popup button, on clicking it, a new window will open and display the content. The link can be from external site. However when I implemented this, the new tab is opening and just after that it popsup to open browser inspite of opening it in webview. I tried with same website link also. For both case it popsup browser. Please help me with a working code to open a new tab and close it programatically. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;


private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);



    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

    String aapp = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36";


    webSettings.setUserAgentString(aapp);


    webView.loadUrl("http://website/test.php");
}

  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {



        if (webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        WebView newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        WebSettings webSettings = newWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String app = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36";

         webSettings.setUserAgentString(app);

        // Other configuration comes here, such as setting the WebViewClient

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(newWebView);
        dialog.show();


        newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }


        });

        ((WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj).setWebView(newWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
}


class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {


        String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
        System.out.println(webUrl);

        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 7):

When a link is touched inside a webpage then depending on a webpage implementation there are two possible scenarios:
1) The link will be opened in the same window.
2) The link will be opened in new window.

For 1st scenario using below code:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Overiding shouldOverrideUrlLoading inside WebViewClient implementation will open link in same window.

For 2nd case, where webpage is requesting a url to be open in new window. For this case we need this:

```
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

and then adding a new web chrome client to webview to get the event when a new window is requested by webpage

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }

});
```

Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you I have done this. But how to do the window.close?  actually first page when clicked open a new window. This new window verify some thing and auto close itself giving a call back request to first page. On log I see that window can only be closed from same source it is originated. Can you tell me a method so that  it can auto close?  This is working in handset browser but not in webview.   Actualy it is a google 0auth for my website.

Comment: Hi was you able to achieve this, I am also stuck in same situation